# Set the window of an eclipse e4 application to have the whole screen size

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

How do I define in the `Application.e4xmi` that I want my window to have as size the whole available screen?
What values should we add to the `Bounds(x,y,w,h)` of the `Trimmed Window`?
I tried `-1,-1,-1,-1` but it does not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the tag `shellMaximized` to the supplementary tab of your `TrimmedWindow` like this:

[image: Screenshot]

See the [Eclipse 4 RCP - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#model_supplementary) by Lars Vogel for more information.