# Set the window of an eclipse e4 application to have based screen size

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I followed the below link to open window size as whole screen size, it's working fine for windows os but linux os small size window is opening.
How to open screen sized window in linux os just like windows os?

[Window Size link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543858/set-the-window-of-an-eclipse-e4-application-to-have-the-whole-screen-size)

Comment: Check out http://techshashwat.blogspot.com/2018/01/how-to-eclipse-e4-rcp-app-full-screen.html

Comment: Are you setting anything in the 'Bounds (x,y,w,h)' fields on the Default tab for the window? If you are try removing them.

Comment: I followed above link in my application but still I am getting small window in Linux OS. It is working fine in Windows OS.

Comment: @Greg-449 I removed them also but still getting small window in LINUX OS..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to maximize the window is to do the following in the `@ProcessAdditions` method of your Life Cycle class (if you have one):

```java
@ProcessAdditions
public void processAdditions(final MApplication app, final EModelService modelService)
{
  MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("id of top window", app);

  Monitor monitor = Display.getCurrent().getPrimaryMonitor();

  Rectangle monitorClientArea = monitor.getClientArea();

  window.setX(monitorClientArea.x);
  window.setY(monitorClientArea.y);
  window.setWidth(monitorClientArea.width);
  window.setHeight(monitorClientArea.height);
}
```